# Maven compilation error while building strongbox

Tags: java, maven, build, strongbox

I am trying to contribute to strongbox repository.

When trying to run mvn clean install i'm receiving the following error:
anyone had this error when building the project?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project strongbox-data-service: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project org.carlspring.strongbox:strongbox-data-service:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
org.carlspring.strongbox:strongbox-db-server:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
org.carlspring.strongbox:strongbox-db-liquibase:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
org.carlspring.strongbox:strongbox-db-import:jar:schema:1.0-SNAPSHOT,
 org.unbroken-dome.liquibase-orientdb:liquibase-orientdb:jar:0.3.0-strongbox-1:
 Could not find artifact org.carlspring.strongbox:strongbox-db-server:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

I thought it's related to the java version first, but mvn -v output is:

```
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_222, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
```

Will be happy to get help in order to solve it,
Thanks.

Comment: The listed artifacts org.carlspring.strongbox:strongbox-db-server:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT could not be resolved which usually means you have not given the correct version/dependency or you have network issue (which I doubt in that case)...but without full pom files etc. I can only make an educated guess not more ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started from: https://strongbox.github.io/developer-guide/building-the-code.html
Instead of: https://strongbox.github.io/developer-guide/getting-started.html
when I added settings.xml everything was fixed.